# Remove 3 first characters of the string

Tags: php, split

I have this code that shows all the directories in the previous page.

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('../*'), 'is_dir');

foreach ($dirs as $nav) {
    echo "<li><a href='$nav'>".$nav."</a></li>";
}
```

The output is like this:

- ../Gėlės
- ../dddd
- ../images

Is there a function or a way that could be used removing `../` prefix from the output string ?

Thank you.

Comment: I knew it!  haha!  Here they come!

Comment: AbraCadavere was voted up by and I am still have 5 minutes waiting until i can accept it. Thanks for help guys :) Could I ask why the basename is the correct answer, but not the substr ?

Comment: 1. _basename — Returns trailing name component of path_ which is exactly what you are doing.  2. What if next time you need to remove `path/tmp/` instead of `../`  or you don't know what the path will be ahead of time?  `basename()` still does it without modification.

Comment: Thanks, really good help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll probably get all kinds of wacky string manipulation answers, so here is the proper tool:

> *basename — Returns trailing name component of path*

Which is exactly what you are doing:

```
basename($nav)
```

Also, use `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag as the second argument in your `glob()` call if you only want directories.

Comment: according to the php manual should be `basename($nav).PHP_EOL`, nice answer although!

Comment: @PedroLobito:  No, only if you want an end-of-line, which doesn't display in rendered HTML anyway, but would make the HTML source wacky to read.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), but I'd go with [AbraCadaver's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver) answer...

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('../*'), 'is_dir');
foreach ($dirs as $nav) {
    $nav = str_replace("../", "", $nav);
    echo "<li><a href='$nav'>$nav</a></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract 3 chars from beginnings like this:

```
echo substr($string, 3);
```